# GitHub does not recognize that pull request was merged from command line

Tags: github, pull-request

To avoid merge commits I merged a pull request on the command line. All the commits were pushed to my *master* branch. What should I do with the pull request now. Is there a way to mark it as merged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None that I know of. Personally I close it manually, then write "Merged as [commit hash]".

Comment: I guess Linus is right that the colorful GitHub UI is actually a turd when it comes to functionality. Thanks for the response!